# Read/Sync data issues between multiple containers that read/write to mysqldb container

Tags: docker, flask-sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I have multiple docker containers

1. One of docker container is mysqldb
2. One containers write data to mysqldb container via Flask SQLAlchemy code
3. Other containers read from mysqldb via Flask SQLAlchemy code

All containers are in running state.

Now if one container writes to mysqldb, i can't access the same data from different containers unless i restart my container.

How can i read data from a running container that is written by some other docker container at same time?

Comment: Making normal SQL requests?  When you say "can't access", what happens?  Can you include any relevant code or setup instructions in the question?

Comment: Cant access means no record found. Once i restart the container i can fetch the record.